# Is it possible to parametize mlflow run name/experiment name instead of hard coding a run name?

Tags: machine-learning, databricks, mlflow

Is it possible to parametize an ml run name or an ml experiment name instead of hard coding the run name?
I Know we can use tags but that is not the same thing.

```
#hard coded run_name
with mlflow.start_run(run_name='random_forest_cat_sci')
```

```
#hard coded experiment name
experiment = mlflow.set_experiment("Social NLP Experiments")
```

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean by parametize? Would using an f string work `f'random_forest_cat_sci_{param_name}'`

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, you cannot.

The experiment must either be specified by name via `experiment_name` or by ID via `experiment_id`. The experiment name and ID cannot both be specified.

If the experiment doesn't exist, you must specify an `experiment_name`. If it exists, you can also activate this experiment with ID as well as experiment name. You can get the experiment ID as follows:

```
# Find the experiment by name
experiment = mlflow.get_experiment_by_name(experiment_name)

# Get the id of the found experiment
experiment_id = experiment.experiment_id
```

However, as you see, you still need the experiment name to get the ID.

You always need to start with something without parametrization.

`run_name` is optional. If a new run is created and `run_name` is not specified, a unique name will be generated for the run.

For more information, you may check out:
https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html#mlflow.set_experiment
https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.html#mlflow.start_run